# Obtaining Air dragon without spending gems

Tags: dragonvale

The Air dragon is awfully expensive. I know you can breed it with an Earth dragon and a Sandstorm dragon or a Dodo dragon, but both of those require either an Air dragon or an Air hybrid dragon to breed.

Is there any (legitimate) way to get an Air dragon without dishing out 500 gems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, just breed a Fire dragon with a Water dragon and you should get an Air dragon. I don't believe there's any other outcome for that breeding pair.